# Rails 4: Check if today is sunday, 15th of month or last day of month

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

A sidekiq worker sending PDF attachment in emails to clients. The worker runs daily checking if its Sunday then sends weekly report, if today is 15th of month then Bi-monthly report and if last day of month then monthly report. The condition looks something like this:

```
if sunday?
  # send weekly
elsif 15th of month
  # send Bi-monthly
elsif last_day_of_month
  # send Monthly
end
```

How to check if its sunday, 15th of month and last day of month ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Rails has many interesting methods for this kind of date calculations:

```
today = Date.today

if today.sunday?
  # send weekly
elsif today.day == 15
  # send bi-monthly
elsif today == today.end_of_month
  # send monthly
end
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed.

Comment: In pure Ruby the `if` and first `elsif` clauses are the same. The last requires part of Rails but could be replaced with `elsif today == Date.new(today.year, today.mon, -1)`, which is pure Ruby.